# How to reduce amount of session locks in Cm_RedisSession_Model_Session::read

Tags: session, redis, locking, magento-1.9

I have a question about Cm_RedisSession Module for Magento. It has built-in locking algorithm.

Method code can be found here: https://github.com/colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract/blob/4671d63212fe05802f21d2fe3086f3425900483e/src/Cm/RedisSession/Handler.php#L401

I get around ~10 failed lock attempts every 30 minutes. which results in unpleasant response time. Is there anything I could tune to boost read/write performance and reduce locks in general?

I run more or less clean Magento 1.9 setup with up-to-date Redis Modules/Libs, all recommended config values, lzf compression and splitted redis instances for session and cache.